# Changing duration for Slider animation doesn't make any difference

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to animate Slider smoothly. My original problem was animating it for 1 second every second for a small value (building an audio player scrubber), but the animation was a split second instead of a full second.

To isolate a problem, I built a playground where I'm trying to animate Slider change from `0` to `maxValue` for `maxValue` number of seconds. However, whatever `maxValue` is, the animation happens in a fraction of a second.

Here is the code:

```
struct SliderTest: View {
    @State private var sliderValue = 0.0
    let maxValue = 30.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...maxValue)
            Button("Animate Slider") {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: maxValue-sliderValue)) {
                    sliderValue = maxValue
                }
            }
            Button("Reset to Random") {
                sliderValue = Double.random(in: 0..<maxValue)
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                sliderValue = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can get the code with a preview for Swift Playgrounds:
https://gist.github.com/OgreSwamp/6e6423d6ef2d26425e3f993042ac208d

Comment: have you solved this somehow?